# View not showing when using modelform

Tags: django, modelform

I'm trying to display a form, using a model form in django. Everything looks like it's setup properly, and I'm not getting any error. Simply, the form is not showing, although the url is updated...

## views.py

```
from rulz.models import Rulz

class rules_create(CreateView):
    model = Rulz
    fields=['title', 'content']
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Rulz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='France')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='Paris')
    player_num = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    complexity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rulz:rulz_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

## urls.py (in the app)

```
app_name = 'rulz'

urlpatterns = [

    #/rulz/
    url(r'^', views.rules_index.as_view(), name='rulz_index'),
    url(r'^index/$', views.rules_index.as_view(), name='rulz_index'),
    # /rulz/details
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.rules_detail.as_view(),name='rulz_detail'),

    #rulz/create
    url(r'^create/',views.rules_create.as_view(),name='rulz_create'),
]
```

## urls.py (root folder)

```
...
url(r'^rules/',include('rulz.urls')),
...
```

## app/templates/app/rulz_form.html

```
{% extends 'rulz/Rulz_base.html' %}

{% block body %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% include 'rulz/form-template.html' %}


{% endblock %}
```

## app/templates/app/form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>


        <div class="validate-input m-b-26" >
            <label class="label-input100">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>

            <div class="input100">{{ field }}</div>

            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and finally the button with the link in my page to access the form :

```
<a href="{% url 'rulz:rulz_create' %}" class="button alt">Go create Rule</a>
```

I really don't know what I am missing. When I click this button, the url is uploaded to http://127.0.0.1:8000/rules/create/ but the displayed page is exactly the same.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView

Comment: what happens if you use {{form}} to display the form in form-template.html?

Comment: exactly the same. The pages refreshes and the url changes, but nothing displayed

Comment: you're using `{% include 'rulz/form-template.html' %}` but your directory structure shows it as app/form-template.html.  Is this a typo?

Comment: yes it is. In reality it the structure is `rulz/templates/rulz/form-template.html`, and django should directly look into `rulz/templates`, that is why I call the template like so `rulz/form-tempalte.html`

Comment: You use form as variable in the templates, but the view does not sent form as variable name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate your index regex. At the moment it matches every string the has a start, which of course means every string. Use the $:

```
url(r'^$', views.rules_index.as_view(), ...
```

(As an aside, you should avoid having two patterns for the same view.)

Comment: This successfully directed me to my form. Now I'll have to do some shaping and adding stuff to the view. Also the first pattern is not meant to be for the same view in the end (I have an homepage being built, but not ready yet).

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView) you can find the list of the attributes needed to correctly rendering your form using `CreateView`.
So, you need to modify your class based view to look like at least this example:

```
from rulz.models import Rulz

class rules_create(CreateView):
    form_class = YOUR_FORM # The form that will be used with this class
    model = Rulz
    fields=['title', 'content']
    success_url = 'YOUR_SUCCESS_URL' # If success redirect to this URL
```

Comment: when doing that it says the `form_class` and `fields` arguments can't be used together as the fields are already specified in the form definition